# JAVA - forced to cast Objects in their own object to apply methods

Tags: java

I have a class `collection<T> extends ArrayList()`
the object lesCommandes is a collection of multiple Commandes
I stock 3 objects from the class Commandes in it and when i want to apply methods to one of them `this.lesCommandes.get(1).xmlCommande()` i need to cast it or it doesn't work `((Commande)this.lesCommandes.get(1)).xmlCommande()`

```
class Collection<T> extends ArrayList{}

this.commande1=new Commande(1,10,"filet 1kg",1,"10-12-2015","10-01-2016","en cours");
this.commande2=new Commande(2,15,"filet 5kg",1,"11-11-2015","10-02-2016","livrée");
this.commande3=new Commande(3,20,"caisse 10kg",2,"12-10-2015","10-03-2016","livrée");
this.lesCommandes.add(0, commande1);
this.lesCommandes.add(1, commande2);
this.lesCommandes.add(2, commande3);
xml=((Commande)this.lesCommandes.get(1)).xmlCommande();
```

Comment: Can you put the relevant code snippets?

Comment: how did you extend ArrayList? did you set T as Commande (`... extends ArrayList<Commande> {`)?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Pierre Pls post the collection class definition, at least the opening line.

Comment: format your question/code, svp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a few advices on design (if I may).

Don't use ***inheritance*** for ***composition***. 
`extends` means *is a* relationship, which is often abused: you can say a `GroupOfOrders` *is a* `ListOfOrders` and define the following (in this case it really means *is implemented in terms of*):

```
public GroupOfOrders extends List<Order> {...}
```

But, it is generally better to define this relation in terms of composition and use the `List<T>` for the (hidden) implementation. 
Why? - because,

1. you may want to have a hierarchy of `GroupOfOrders` and you can only `extends` once,
2. when you `extends` you inherit *all* the public and protected members from the super class. in your case, these methods are not part of the (functional) domain. You may not really want to allow clients of your class to apply any methods from `List<T>`.
3. If you decide to change the implementation and say that a `GroupOfOrders` is actually better implemented with a `Set<T>`, meaning you don't authorise the duplicate `Order` into a `GroupOfOrders`, you can easily do it if you *don't* extends 'List`. It can be very difficult if you extends`List` and client classes use methods from it all over the code - it can be even worse if there are *external* clients from whom you don't control the code and usage of your class.

Just for the example, I defined the `Order` class (*commande* in english is *order* - It's just a matter of sharing with people, I don't mean you need to translate the code)

```
public class Order {
   // properties, constructor...

   public OrderResult executeOrder() {
      // just do it
   }
   public String asXML() {
      // generate the order as an XML string
   }
}    

public class GroupOfOrders {
   private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

   public void addOrder(Order o) {
      // do some checking on order
      orders.add(order);
   }

   public GroupedOrderResult executeAllOrders() {
      GroupedOrderResult result = new GroupedOrderResult();
      for (Commande c : commandes) {
         OrderResult res = c.executeOrder();
         result.add(c, res);
      }
      return result;
   }

   List<Order> getOrders() { return orders; }
}
```

And maybe, somewhere else in the program, when you need to get each order as an XML string:

```
GroupOfOrders orders; // initialised with the different orders
for (Order o : orders.getOrders()) {
   String xmlOrder = o.asXML();
   // do what needs to be done with xmlOrder
}
```

You will note that there is nowhere a need to cast.

---

Second, a few comments on the code you provided:

> ```
> class Collection<T> extends ArrayList{}
> ```

This doesn't make sense: an `ArrayList` already implements `Collection` interface. May be you mean you have

```
List<T> lesCommandes = new ArrayList<Commande>();
```

> ```
> this.commande1=new Commande(1,10,"filet 1kg",1,"10-12-2015","10-01-2016","en cours");
> this.commande2=new Commande(2,15,"filet 5kg",1,"11-11-2015","10-02-2016","livrée");
> this.commande3=new Commande(3,20,"caisse 10kg",2,"12-10-2015","10-03-2016","livrée");
> this.lesCommandes.add(0, commande1);
> this.lesCommandes.add(1, commande2);
> this.lesCommandes.add(2, commande3);
> ```

Just do

```
lesCommandes.add(commande1); etc..
```

The `List<T>$add(T)` will actually add at the end of the list and manage the size dynamically.

> xml=((Commande)this.lesCommandes.get(1)).xmlCommande();

If `lesCommandes` is defined as I suggest and there is a `xmlCommande()` method in the `Commande` class, then just do

```
xml = lesCommandes.get(1).xmlCommande();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend `ArrayList<Commande>`, so the objects stored in it will remain of `Commande` type

Comment: As a matter of fact, the `Commandes` class should _be composed of_ `Commande`, and then declare a member `ArrayList<Commade>` but not `extends` it.